# Using Protractor with traditional Selenium Webdriver 2.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have written Page Object Model in Java for Selenium Web Driver but My application is in Angular JS. Recently, I came across Protractor and think of switching to Protractor. Is there any way I can move my Selenium Page Models to Protractor without rewriting in Protractor. I want my code in Java still be useful, don't want to throw it away.

Answer (score 1):

Possible!

There is a [protractor-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Protractor/) port. But, unfortunately there is no such port for Java yet, at least not that I know of. However, I just want to point out you do not have to rewrite the full test suite only for Angular pages. If possible rewrite that port and use. This works pretty awesome. I am using it currently with existing framework.